# Adding delay in between 2 threads running one after another

Tags: java, multithreading

I"M TRYING TO PUT A 5 SECONDS GAP BETWEEN 2 THREADS,THAT RUNS ONE AFTER ANOTHER I.E. SUPPOSE MY 1ST THREAD PRINTS "X" ,THERE WILL BE 5 SECONDS DELAY & THEN ANOTHER THREAD IS PRINTED "Y", AGAIN 5 SECONDS DELAY & THEN "X" & THIS IS GOES ON , SAY 30 TIMES.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
class PingPong implements Runnable
{   String word;
    PingPong(String s){
     word = s;
    }

    public void run()
    {

    try

    {

         for(int  i = 0; i<30; i++)

          {
              System.out.println(word);
              Thread.sleep(100) ;
           }
    } catch (InterruptedException e)

     { e.printStackTrace(); }

   }
   public static void main(String[] args){

     Runnable p1 =  new PingPong("ping");

     Thread  t1 = new Thread(p1);

     t1.start();
     Runnable p2 = new PingPong("pong");

     Thread t2 = new Thread(p2);
     t2.start();
    }
 }
```

Comment: How are you expecting the two threads to know about each other if they are running concurrently independently?

Comment: Plase format your question, why do you use caps? And where is your attempt? All I see is two instances of one thread printing a word every 100ms

Comment: Use the observer pattern, for this kind of task

Answer (score 1):

Threads are independent of each other unless you introduce some kind of synchronisation mechanism. So the first thing you need to do is change your PingPong class to take something to synchronize on, on which each thread is going to wait.

Let's call this object `ball`. You can pass it in the constructor of `PingPong`. It can be any object you want (even just Object) or you can create your own small class for it.

Then in your loop, you can do:

```
synchronized(ball) {
  System.out.println(word);
  Thread.sleep(5000);
}
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

This way each thread will block for 5seconds until it allows another thread to 'take' the ball's monitor and output it's word.

The second sleep is arbitrary but important so that the same thread doesn't get the monitor again.

A slightly more complex but more correct way to do it is to use a second `ReentrantLock`. Again you have to pass it through the constructor together with the previous `ball` object. Let's call this `lock`.

```
lock.lock();
synchronized(ball) {
  try {
    System.out.println(word);
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }

  Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

The `unlock()` is in a `finally` block to ensure that if any exception is thrown the lock doesn't remain locked forever.

The `System.out` didn't actually need to be inside the `try` block, but this makes the code a bit more elegant, rather than having an empty `try`. The `sleep()` has to be outside, to make sure the other thread goes in through the first lock while this thread is sleeping.

This ensures that if thread *Ping* is sleeping, thread *Pong* takes the `lock`, so it will be next to go inside the `synchronized` block. When *Ping* wakes up and goes out of the `synchronized` block, even if coincidentally gets scheduled before *Pong*, it won't be able to proceed because it can't take the lock, and has to wait for *Pong* to go inside the `synchronized` block and output its word.

Comment: *[...] that the same thread doesn't get the monitor again.* I think java takes care of that, as the second thread waits on the first to release the monitor, and then immediatly grabs the ball if it is released. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee for that because there is no guarantee of a thread context switch when the synchronized block ends. I could be wrong too... Will check.

Comment: @Lino Didn't manage to find much information yet, apart from the fact that `synchronized` doesn't guarantee any thread scheduling fairness. This is amplified even more if a thread happens to have a higher priority than the other, which could lead to starvation, with the lower priority thread barely getting any CPU time. I would say better play it safe, and make sure race conditions are handled tightly. I added another way to do it.

Comment: Anyway thank you for the research, nice answer btw. Would upvote again if I could :) I don't really like the way of using two different locking mechanisms though, but I guess there is no other way around it.

Comment: Well, the `ReentrantLock` was added for these kind of situations, where you couldn't overlap 2 `synchronized` blocks. To be fair, the question is a bit of a weird one, I don't think it is that common to have these kinds of loops handing over to each other (you might as well do it as a single threaded loop with 2 sleeps).

Comment: I agree, this problem could've probably be solved with the observer pattern as I've mentioned under the question. Where both threads are an observer of the other thread. And after they did their job, inform the other to do it's action. But this approach is also rather messy as it's a circular reference.